# Growth rate of inverse of sum of integers made of first $k$ primes

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

**Question:** I conjecture that

$$\sum_{z_i\in\mathbb{N}_0}\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{-z_i}=O(\ln(k))$$

Basically, the sum over the inverse of the integers made up of the first $k$ primes (and $1$) grows like $\ln(k)$. For example

$$k=1:\ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}=2$$

$$k=2:\ \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i 3^j}=3$$

**Work:** Numerically this seems to be true and it makes sense because as $k$ goes to infinity this series looks more and more like the harmonic series (at least in a handwavy way). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make any significant progress on proving this.

**Motivation:** This question would settle a different [question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198004/convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-frac1nqn-lambda/4198583#4198583). If we could prove the above conjecture, then the linked question would have an affirmative answer for all $\lambda>0$. The original question might still be true even if this conjecture is incorrect. If it turns out to be $O(\ln(k)\ln(\ln(k)))$ or something sub polynomial like that it would still work.

Comment: Technically $f(k)=O(g(k))$ means that $f(k)$ grows no faster than $g(k)$. I think you are likely to be more interested in $f(k)=\Theta(g(k)),$ meaning that they grow at the same rate, up to a constant factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i3^j}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^j}\right)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}.
$$

Similarly, doing the first $k$ primes gives
$$
\prod_{1\le i \le k}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}}.
$$

By Merten's third theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) this product grows at a comparable rate to  $\ln p_k.$ Since $p_k \approx k\ln k$ we get $\ln(p_k)\approx \ln (k\ln k)=\ln k + \ln \ln k \approx \ln k.$